# is it possible way to customize the sub resource api platform?

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

The goal was i aiming to is to change identifier from id of entity to JWT token that user has attached at specific path.

```
  @ApiResource(
       itemOperations = {
               "get" ={
                   "security" = "is_granted('VIEW',object)",
                   "normalization_context" = {"groups" = {"read"}}
               },
               "put" = {
                   "security" = "is_granted('WRITE',object)",
                   "normalization_context" = {"groups" = {"get"}},
                   "denormalization_context" = {"groups" = {"put"}}
               },
               "api_users_cart_subresource" = {
                   "method" = "GET",
                   "path" = "/users/{id}/carts",
                   "security" = "is_granted('VIEW',object)",
                   "normalization_context" = {"groups" = {"user:cart"}}
               }
           },
       collectionOperations = {
               "post" = {
                   "denormalization_context" = {"groups" = {"post"}},
                   "normalization_context" = {"groups" = {"get"}}
               },
               "get" = {
                   "access_control" = "is_granted('ROLE_ADMIN')",
                   "normalization_context" = {"groups" = {"admin:read"}}
               }
           }
 )
```

**is it possible to change the path to `/users/carts` and return normalized data that belong to the user base from their token?**

ps. sorry for my grammar